# Function to print all permutations of all subsets of the array

Tags: c++, math, recursion

print out all the possible **subsets of set** and every possible **rearrangement for each subset**.

Ex: **s = [ 1 , 2 ]**
subsets of **s = [ [ ], [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 1, 2 ] ],**
every possible permutation of each subset: **[ [ ], [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ] ],**

Comment: Don't post images or links to images. Copy the code that you have trouble with and post that here. Also read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i couldn't enter my code as it was writing your code has no proper alignment or something like this so sorry

Comment: [link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-program-that-prints-all-subsets-of-set-and-all-possible-positioning-for-each-subset?__snids__=1554852494&__nsrc__=2)
same question here

Comment: You are looking for combinations of the set, not subsets, since different order yields different objects for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to get you an idea how to do it(you have to write your code on your own, especially since I dont write C++). The best way to do this is recursion:

```
getSubcombinations(Combination comb, Set set){
     for a in set{
         newSet=set \ {a}
         getSubcombinations(comb+a, newSet)
     }
     print(comb);
}
```

The method calls itself, increasing the current subset with an element "a" and every combination of the restset (set without a) and also gives out the current subset if you dont add further elements. If your set has no duplicates (it is a set!), this wont yield duplicate combinations (that is what you are asking for, not subsets!).

Comment: thanks for answer but I didn't get what is second set which is needed for function and what "a" is ?

Comment: `a` is an element of the set you give the method. The first parameter is the current combination you have, the second parameter is the set of elements not occuring in the combination (which are still free to choose from).

Comment: It's not a valid C++ code/types. It's just general algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void subsets(int n, int r)
    {
    std::vector<bool> v(n);
    std::fill(v.begin(), v.begin() + r, true);

    do  {
        std::vector<int> p;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
            if (v[i]) 
                p.push_back(i);
        do  {
            std::cout << " { ";
            for(auto i : p)
                std::cout << i << ' ';
            std::cout << "} ";
            } while(std::next_permutation(p.begin(), p.end()));
        } while (std::prev_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    }

void subsets(int n)
    {
    for(int r=0; r<=n; ++r)
        subsets(n, r);
    }

int main() 
    { 
    subsets(4); 
    }
```