# How to assign many subsets to their largest supersets?

Tags: algorithm

My data has large number of sets (few millions). Each of those set size is between few members to several tens of thousands integers. Many of those sets are subsets of larger sets (there are many of those super-sets). I'm trying to assign each subset to it's largest superset.

Please can anyone recommend algorithm for this type of task?
There are many algorithms for generating all possible sub-sets of a set, but this type of approach is time-prohibitive given my data size (e.g. this [paper](http://applied-math.org/subset.pdf) or [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291070/how-to-create-program-that-prints-all-subsets-of-set-and-all-possible-positionin)).

Example of my data-set:

```
A {1, 2, 3}
B {1, 3}
C {2, 4}
D {2, 4, 9}
E {3, 5}
F {1, 2, 3, 7}
```

Expected answer: B and A are subset of F (it's not important B is also subset of A); C is a subset of D; E remains unassigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea that might work:

- Build a table that maps number to a sorted list of sets, sorted first by size with largest first, and then, by size, arbitrarily but with some canonical order. (Say, alphabetically by set name.) So in your example, you'd have a table that maps `1` to `[F, A, B]`, `2` to `[F, A, D, C]`, `3` to `[F, A, B, E]` and so on. This can be implemented to take `O(n log n)` time where `n` is the total size of the input.
- For each set in the input:

  - fetch the lists associated with each entry in that set. So for `A`, you'd get the lists associated with 1, 2, and 3. The total number of selects you'll issue in the runtime of the whole algorithm is O(n), so runtime so far is O(n log n + n) which is still O(n log n).
  - Now walk down each list simultaneously. If a set is the first entry in all three lists, then it's the largest set that contains the input set. Output that association and continue with the next input list. If not, then discard the smallest item among all the items in the input lists and try again. Implementing this last bit is tricky, but you can store the heads of all lists in a heap and get (IIRC) something like O(n log k) overall runtime where k is the maximum size of any individual set, so you can bound that at O(n log n) in the worst case.

So if I got everything straight, the runtime of the algorithm is overall O(n log n), which seems like probably as good as you're going to get for this problem.

Here is a python implementation of the algorithm:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
import heapq

def LargestSupersets(setlists):
  '''Computes, for each item in the input, the largest superset in the same input.

setlists: A list of lists, each of which represents a set of items. Items must be hashable.
  '''
  # First, build a table that maps each element in any input setlist to a list of records
  # of the form (-size of setlist, index of setlist), one for each setlist that contains
  # the corresponding element
  element_to_entries = defaultdict(list)
  for idx, setlist in enumerate(setlists):
    entry = (-len(setlist), idx)  # cheesy way to make an entry that sorts properly -- largest first
    for element in setlist:
      element_to_entries[element].append(entry)

  # Within each entry, sort so that larger items come first, with ties broken arbitrarily by
  # the set's index
  for entries in element_to_entries.values():
    entries.sort()

  # Now build up the output by going over each setlist and walking over the entries list for
  # each element in the setlist. Since the entries list for each element is sorted largest to
  # smallest, the first entry we find that is in every entry set we pulled will be the largest
  # element of the input that contains each item in this setlist. We are guaranteed to eventually
  # find such an element because, at the very least, the item we're iterating on itself is in
  # each entries list.
  output = []
  for idx, setlist in enumerate(setlists):
    num_elements = len(setlist)
    buckets = [element_to_entries[element] for element in setlist]

    # We implement the search for an item that appears in every list by maintaining a heap and
    # a queue. We have the invariants that:
    #   1. The queue contains the n smallest items across all the buckets, in order
    #   2. The heap contains the smallest item from each bucket that has not already passed through
    #        the queue.
    smallest_entries_heap = []
    smallest_entries_deque = deque([], num_elements)
    for bucket_idx, bucket in enumerate(buckets):
      smallest_entries_heap.append((bucket[0], bucket_idx, 0))
    heapq.heapify(smallest_entries_heap)

    while (len(smallest_entries_deque) < num_elements or
           smallest_entries_deque[0] != smallest_entries_deque[num_elements - 1]):
      # First extract the next smallest entry in the queue ...
      (smallest_entry, bucket_idx, element_within_bucket_idx) = heapq.heappop(smallest_entries_heap)
      smallest_entries_deque.append(smallest_entry)

      # ... then add the next-smallest item from the bucket that we just removed an element from
      if element_within_bucket_idx + 1 < len(buckets[bucket_idx]):
        new_element = buckets[bucket_idx][element_within_bucket_idx + 1]
        heapq.heappush(smallest_entries_heap, (new_element, bucket_idx, element_within_bucket_idx + 1))

    output.append((idx, smallest_entries_deque[0][1]))

  return output
```

Note: don't trust my writeup too much here. I just thought of this algorithm right now, I haven't proved it correct or anything.

Comment: A single comparison of two things of size `m` is `O(m)`.  Now repeat the operation `n` times to get all of them at once.  Your complexity ballooned.  By a lot.

Comment: Where am I comparing two things of size m? If you're talking about the sort in the first set, you don't need to do that; just precompute set size.

Comment: When you compare two sets to sort the list of sets, how expensive are the compares?

Comment: Constant -- you never need to actually compare sets, just their sizes and index within the input. I just updated my answer with a Python implementation to clarify this kind of finicky detail.

Comment: Thank you @jacobm ! The sorting by size will significantly reduce space where supersets could be.
I'm just afraid the second condition ("if the set is the **first entry of each list**") is too strict. E.g. "D" is the biggest superset of "C", but it will be on second or third place for number 2[F, A, **D**, C].
Am I missing something or should the condition be:
a) biggest superset is member of each related list (2[F, A, **D**, C] and 4[**D**, C])
b) has the highest position in comparison with all other sets present in all lists

Comment: I didn't explain that idea very well. If _all_ lists have the same first item, then that item is your answer. If they don't, then you discard the smallest element among all lists and loop again. So in your example, you start with `2[F, A, D, C]` and `4[D,C]`; since they don't start with the same element, you discard the `F` from the first list and try again. Now you have `[A,D,C]` and `[D,C]`. You still don't have the same first element, so you discard `A`. Now you have `[D,C]` and `[D,C]`. They all have the same first element `D`, so you return `D`, which is correct.

Comment: "For each set in the input fetch the lists associated with each entry in that set. [...] Now walk down each list simultaneously". This alone suggests at least O(n * n * m).

Answer (score 0):

So you have millions of sets, with thousands of elements each.  Just representing that dataset takes billions of integers.  In your comparisons you'll quickly get to trillions of operations without even breaking a sweat.

Therefore I'll assume that you need a solution which will distribute across a lot of machines.  Which means that I'll think in terms of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce.  A series of them.

1. Read the sets in, mapping them to k:v pairs of `i: s` where `i` is an element of the set `s`.
2. Receive a key of an integers, along with a list of sets.  Map them off to pairs `(s1, s2): i` where `s1 <= s2` are both sets that included to `i`.  Do not omit to map each set to be paired with itself!
3. For each pair `(s1, s2)` count the size `k` of the intersection, and send off pairs `s1: k`, `s2: k`.  (Only send the second if `s1` and `s2` are different.
4. For each set `s` receive the set of supersets.  If it is maximal, send off `s: s`.  Otherwise send off `t: s` for every `t` that is a *strict* superset of `s`.
5. For each set `s`, receive the set of subsets, with `s` in the list only if it is maximal.  If `s` is maximal, send off `t: s` for every `t` that is a subset of `s`.
6. For each set we receive the set of maximal sets that it is a subset of.  (There may be many.)

There are a lot of steps for this, but at its heart it requires repeated comparisons between pairs of sets with a common element for each common element.  Potentially that is `O(n * n * m)` where `n` is the number of sets and `m` is the number of distinct elements that are in many sets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple suggestion for an algorithm that might give better results based on your numbers (n = 10^6 to 10^7 sets with m = 2 to 10^5 members, a lot of super/subsets). Of course it depends a lot on your data. Generally speaking complexity is much worse than for the other proposed algorithms. Maybe you could only process the sets with less than X, e.g. 1000 members that way and for the rest use the other proposed methods.

1. Sort the sets by their size.
2. Remove the first (smallest) set and start comparing it against the others from behind (largest set first).
3. Stop as soon as you found a superset and create a relation. Just remove if no superset was found.
4. Repeat 2. and 3. for all but the last set.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Excel, you could structure it as follows:
1) Create a cartesian plot as a two-way table that has all your data sets as titles on both the side and the top
2) In a seperate tab, create a row for each data set in the first column, along with a second column that will count the number of entries (ex: F has 4) and then just stack FIND(",") and MID formulas across the sheet to split out all the entries within each data set. Use the counter in the second column to do COUNTIF(">0"). Each variable you find can be your starting point in a subsequent FIND until it runs out of variables and just returns a blank.
3) Go back to your cartesian plot, and bring over the separate entries you just generated for your column titles (ex: F is 1,2,3,7). Use an AND statement to then check that each entry in your left hand column is in your top row data set using an OFFSET to your seperate area and utilizing your counter as the width for the OFFSET

Comment: You do realize how large the problem size is, don't you?

Comment: Welcome to your spreadsheet a few million columns wide and a few million columns high

Comment: True, but that underlying logic could still be used in R or SQL to essentially do the same thing (since he was asking for an algorithm). But yes, for a dataset this large it definitely won't work in Excel