# Merge rows in a Pandas Dataframe filling NaN values and removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, pandas-merge

I'm trying to clean a Python `Pandas dataframe` that contains dirty data with **"repeated" (but not exactly duplicated)** people information.

```
id  name    name2   name3   email
1   A       A       A       email@gmail.com
1   A       NaN     NaN     NaN
NaN A       A       B       email@gmail.com
NaN A       A       B       email@gmail.com
1   A       A       B       NaN
NaN A       A       A       email@gmail.com
```

Unfortunately I don't have a clear "primary key" since the column `id` is not always set and I have a list of different names (`name`,`name2`,`name3`) that don't match always (sometime I have the same `name` but different `name2`).
I'd like to keep both these information, but removing duplicate rows and "**merging**" rows in order to remove the maximum number of NaN values, without loosing any king of information.

The output should be that:

```
id  name    name2   name3   email
1   A       A       A       email@gmail.com
1   A       A       B       email@gmail.com
```

The second row is given by the merge between

```
NaN A       A       B       email@gmail.com
1   A       A       B       NaN
```

in the original dataframe.

(I already tried the solution here: [How can I merge duplicate rows and fill the NaN cells with the values from the other row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588957/how-can-i-merge-duplicate-rows-and-fill-the-nan-cells-with-the-values-from-the-o) but without success)

Thanks.

Comment: This is more of a clustering problem than simply filling missing values, more like this question really: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43927449/4800086

Comment: @Swier I was also wondering, but in this case OP should provide a much better example (more ids, more names, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the example is unclear, but IIUC, `ffill` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
out = df.ffill().drop_duplicates()
```

output:

```
    id name name2 name3            email
0  1.0    A     A     A  email@gmail.com
2  1.0    A     A     B  email@gmail.com
```